# Search option in my page

Tags: android

I am developing a app based on Question and Answers.

I am using res/raw database to fetch the data,
 I am planning to have a search option for that ie,
 I kept a searchbox at bottom and say i have 100 questions,
 The thing i want to do is to goto question no 45. by entering the number in searchbox. 
 I dont have any idea in working on this.
 Please help me to find a solution

```
protected void loadQuestionset1() throws Exception {
try {
InputStream questionset1 = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.raw.questionset1);
bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questionset1));
StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
            String aJsonLine = null;
            while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                quesString.append(aJsonLine);
            }
Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
            JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
            quesList1 = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                    "Num Questions " + quesList1.length());
            }
catch (Exception e){

            } finally {
                try {
                    bReader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
                }

            }


        }
public static JSONArray getQuesList1() {
            return quesList1;
        }
```

Comment: write your own search code . get data of 45th question and display.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public  ArrayList<NewQuestion> questionList=new ArrayList<NewQuestion>();
```

Every time you get question from data base

```
 NewQuestion newQuestion=new NewQuestion();     
 newQuestion.question.put(NewQuestion.QUESTION_TEXT,q);
 newQuestion.question.put(NewQuestion.OPTION_1,q);
 newQuestion.question.put(NewQuestion.QPTION_2,q);
 newQuestion.question.put(NewQuestion.OPTION_3,q);
 newQuestion.question.put(NewQuestion.OPTION_4,q);    
 questionList.add(newQuestion);     


 public class NewQuestion {

 public static List<String> q12=new ArrayList<String>();
 public static final String QUESTION_TEXT="questionText";
 public static final String OPTION_1="option1";
 public static final String OPTION_2="option2";
 public static final String OPTION_3="option3";
 public static final String OPTION_4="option4";
 public static final String CORRECT_ANSWER="answer";

 Hashtable question=new Hashtable();

 public NewQuestion()
 {

    question.put(NewQuestion.QUESTION_TEXT,new String());
    question.put(NewQuestion.OPTION_1,new String());
    question.put(NewQuestion.OPTION_2,new String());
    question.put(NewQuestion.OPTION_3,new String());
    question.put(NewQuestion.OPTION_4,new String());
    question.put(NewQuestion.CORRECT_ANSWER,new String());
}
}
```

Now your questionList of 0(index 0) will contain data related to question 1. When user types 40, you can access data at 40

```
        newQuestion=(NewQuestion)questionList.get(questionNo);//question no 45

        String q=newQuestion.question.get(NewQuestion.QUESTION_TEXT).toString();//get question
         String op1=newQuestion.question.get(NewQuestion.OPTION_1).toString();
         String op2=newQuestion.question.get(NewQuestion.OPTION_2).toString();
         String op3=newQuestion.question.get(NewQuestion.OPTION_3).toString();
         String op4=newQuestion.question.get(NewQuestion.OPTION_4).toString();
```

If you can access questionset at position 45 directly form your raw database no need to use the above. The above procedure is not ideal as arraylist stores all data. As and when the sizes increaes may slow down the operation.

If you a database(sqlite) for storing questions and answers, it will be easier to fetch data from data base usin queries.